# Blocking screen sharing when accessing a given website

Tags: screen-sharing

The company I'm working has a paid product consisting of Windows virtual machines running on Azure. Clients pay for a subscription, receive credentials for accessing such machines through Apache Guacamole and can effectively access them through any web browser (i.e., the company is not controlling the machines from where access originates).

Network access from inside the VMs are strictly controlled and clients can access a set of predefined resources. Copy & Paste Guacamole features are disabled. Besides, moving files from/to the VM is controlled by a human verification process.

Lately, a new "requirement" has appeared. The company wants to impose Digital Rights Management (DRI) policies, and I was assigned the task of finding mechanism to block screen sharing when a client is using a VM he has paid for. My research on this subject has shown me that it's not possible to block such feature without other softwares being installed on client's machine. However, I'd like to double check with you.

Is it possible, for instance, to prevent a user of using Zoom for sharing screen when accessing a given web site? Concretely, not allowing the user to create a meeting and share the screen with unauthorized people?

Comment: Yes; It’s possible to enforce a group policy that prevents screen share within Zoom.  It’s also possible to enforce a group policy with a BYOD situation. However, it won’t be possible to prevent screen sharing if you can’t enforce group policies on the machine accessing the VM.

Comment: Remember that (so far as in my own testing ) that a host screen capture tool can capture the VM screen without the VM knowing.

Comment: @Ramhound I completely agree with you, if I can't control client's laptop/desktop used to access to VM, I can't really prevent screen-sharing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, it is impossible to restrict anything when it comes to viewing if you don't have control over what is viewing it.

In case of access to a VM, if you don't have access to the method of viewing the VM, you cannot block anything.

Lets take it very literal. Lets say, you manage everything from the client computer all the way to the VM access. Even then, you cannot prevent 2 people watching the same screen.

In the same way, it is going to be impossible to restrict access if someone sets up the following scenario: They have one dummy computer setup with access to your VM, then they use something like VNC to remote into that dummy pc from multiple locations and view the same thing.

So long answer short, there is always a way around it, but you can make it harder, sure.

If you can ensure that from the client, special software is required in order to access your VM, then you can use that client software to control how much of it can do, eg: assign a username/password to its connection, and if a 2nd user from another client connects using the same username/password, they get an access denied error.

But again, there are ways around it, it will become impractical at some point, which is the best you can do. Make it hard enough for people to just not want to go that route, and either decide to pay for whatever you want them to, or find an alternative and leave your service behind.

Comment: You can disable remote downloading of files in an Azure Office 365 environment but even the largest employers can’t prevent taking screenshots of VM while viewing it in something like Horizon View.

Comment: There are of course DRI applications, similar to those used by testing centers, to prevent cheating. They disable keyboard shortcuts to prevent screenshots from being taken. However, you can only do so much, if DRI is that important then implement strong machine management and don’t let outside devices into a heavily controlled and monitored environment.